# JavaScript on scroll to shrink logo AND menu bar

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress site, I have used the following JavaScript code to shrink the logo on scroll:

logo has id `#logoid`

CSS

```
.logoclass {width:100%; 
transition: width 0.5s linear;}

.scroll {margin-top:-10px;
width:55%;
transition: width 0.5s linear;}
```

Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = () => {
const nav = document.querySelector('#logoid');
if(this.scrollY <= 250) nav.className = 'logoclass'; else nav.className =  
'scroll';};
</script>
```

Now this works fine to simply shrink the image and restore size.

Now I have two problems:

1. Since I'm using WordPress plugins, there are many attributes applied
   to the logo internally and are not in my `.logoclass` or in the 
   `.scroll` so these attributes get removed once I scroll and do not
   get applied again. Is there a way to :

   - a) On scroll down ONLY change size while keeping other attributes
     intact
   - b) On scroll up revert to initial settings completely    (remove new
     class)

My second question is, I want to also modify the menu bar size on scroll, but I cannot use the same code twice because it seems to only accept the code written last. Possibly because `windows.onscroll` gets added twice. Any way to incorporate both?

Comment: if you're OK with IE10+ for compatibility, you can look into the `.classList` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp to add/remove your classname without effecting the other classnames already assigned.

Comment: Hi @Doug, yes I tried it and it works for problem 1. this is the javascript:

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var $nav = $('.logoclass');
    var scrolTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrolTop > 200) {
      $nav.addClass("scroll");
    } else {
      $nav.removeClass("scroll");
    }
  });

</script>

This ads the new class that shrinks it then removes the class. This is perfect. 

Any solution for problem two? How can I incorporate two changes into one on scroll?

Comment: for #2 you should be able to resolve that with curly braces for your if/else condition (without the braces, just the next single line will be executed, with them everything inside the braces will be executed).  for example `if( y <= 250 ){ ... }else{ ... }` between the braces you can have multiple lines and all the craziness you'd like.

Comment: Can you show the code that isn't working for #2?

Comment: Another idea! If you want to change the CSS at the same time between two elements, instead of adding the CSS directly to the elements, add it to their parent container (or the body).  For example you can target the body tag to get `<body class="scroll">` but then write some CSS like `#menu{ height: 100px; } body.scroll #menu{ height: 20px; }`

Comment: @doug wow! that worked! thank you!

Comment: @bmceldowney I very stupidly simply copied the entire javascript code and pasted it again with the new class values for the menu. Then the menu javascript worked but not the one for the logo that was pasted above it. I thought it would just execute one after the other, but apparently, it doesn't. Now I used Doug's advice (above this comment) and added the menu bar's class changing code within the same curly braces.

Comment: Thanks, this works. one last query, since the onscroll changes differ on different devices, I can simply add the old and new classes inside the device definers right? that is, mobile classes within 
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){ logoid etc etc} and so on, while keeping the javascript constant?

Comment: @HugoNoro: when adding or editing lists in questions, you don't need to format the Markdown with line breaks and space alignments. It makes no difference to the HTML output, but it does make subsequent editing harder (since maintaining the tidy alignment is more work than most editors are willing to undertake). I'd advise just keeping it in a single line.

Comment: @halfer: good point. Thank you for the insight. Will have it in consideration :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #1, you should use the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property to add or remove classes.

For #2, you should be able to add whatever changes you want in the same if statement.

```js
window.onscroll = () => {
  const nav = document.querySelector('#logoid');
  const menu = document.querySelector('#menubar');
  if (this.scrollY <= 250) {
    nav.classList.remove('scroll');
    menu.classList.remove('someclass');
  } else {
    nav.classList.add('scroll');
    menu.classList.add('someclass');
  }
};
```

```css
.logoclass {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

.scroll {
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 55%;
  transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#logoid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoid" class="logoclass"></div>
<div id="menubar" class="menuclass"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. one last query, since the onscroll changes differ on different devices, I can simply add the old and new classes inside the device definers right? that is, mobile classes within 
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){ logoid etc etc} and so on, while keeping the javascript constant?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a global scroll class to your `body` tag you won't have to change your JavaScript if you want to change more things on scroll, only your CSS.

```js
window.onscroll = () => {
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  if (this.scrollY <= 250) {
    body.classList.remove('scroll');
  } else {
    body.classList.add('scroll');
  }
};
```

```css
.logoclass {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

.scroll .logoclass, .scroll .menuclass {
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 55%;
  transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#logoid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoid" class="logoclass"></div>
<div id="menubar" class="menuclass"></div>
```

If you wan't to run multiple functions on scroll you should use `addEventListener`.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { 
    doSomething(); 
});
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { 
    doSomeOtherThing();
});
```